# Java forcing a TCP socket to send data immediately

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, flush

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445734/forcing-a-tcp-socket-to-flush-in-java) and other questions related to this but did not get any direct answer.

I need to send data to the client immediately for performance issue. I don't need Nagle's algorithm to efficiently send data.

```
Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
sock.setTcpNoDelay​();
OutputStream output = sock.getOutputStream();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    output.write(dataByteArray);
    output.flush();
    Thread.sleep(delayTime);
}
```

My question is: as I have set `sock.setTcpNoDelay​()` do I really need to use `output.flush()` to request OS to send network buffer data immediately?

Comment: Yes, Nagle is different than buffering.  You still need to call flush().

Comment: @markspace, if you are sure about then submit this as an answer and I will make it accepted the answer.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but reading the wiki page that's what I get out of it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm